# RoR3/HTML: Many check boxes, different actions on those checked items, howto?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, web

I have a page which lists several messages, and each of these messages has a checkbox. Then, I can either "delete" or "save" those checked items (different actions for each one). How can I accomplish to have this behavior on rails3?

Just to picture it, this is my page: http://cl.ly/1x2d3K3y2z3o071c401L. I can select several messages and either Delete or Save them. I am uncertain on how to proceed. First, these checkboxes have nothing to do with my model, therefore, form_for can't be used. Then. IF I should use form_tag, I do not know how to use the SAME checkboxes (they must be the same, just the action can change, according to the clicked button) for two possible different actions.

If I use "check_box_tag(message_id)" not inside a "form_tag", and then use normal links to the corresponding actions on the "delete" and "save" buttons, would there be any way to get those checkboxes values, according to their names? I am really lost here. Any direction lead is greatly welcome :)

Thanks in advance,
Fernando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simplest option is to adapt this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes to your requirements and use Rails 3 syntax by using <%= opening erb tags for from_tag declarations instead of just <% opening tags

**Update**
To use multiple submit tags see my answer to a similar question here [How should I handle triggering an "action method" through a RESTful Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796832/how-should-i-handle-triggering-an-action-method-through-a-restful-controller/6796944#6796944)

Comment: I was experimenting with similar things, but the problem is that there he has just one possible action on the selected items. I want to use the same checkboxes either for Deleting or Saving. The form_tag, as far as I know, works with only one possible action, as on that link :/

Comment: Just have multiple submit tags and interrogate the text used on the button in the params hash e.g. if params[:commit] == 'Delete' then do something

Comment: But then I would need to commit those two to the same action, and on that action, handle the two possibilities (based on params[:commit]), right? Do you thing it is alright to create a non CRUD action for Deleting and saving? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would personally use a restful route to an action called something like update_or_delete_multiple on the same controller. Keeps things nice and readable but this is one scenario where personal preference takes precedence over convention